# How to Clear IOS Keychain for before App Initialization During Tests

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xctest

When testing, I need to clear the ios keychain store for my app before the 
initialization code runs in my initial viewController's "viewDidLoad." This seems to happen before anything I have access to.  Things I've tried:

1. Replacing the AppDelegate with a MockAppDelegate (doesn't work because the initial AppDelegate code executes and breaks the test before I can replace it)
2. clearing the keychain in XCTest setup() (of course)
3. clearing the keychain after each test (doesn't work for the first test)

How do I clear the keychain before my app is initialized?  I would imagine it would be easiest to do this before the AppDelegate is initialized -- does XCTest provide any way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why did the AppDelegate still execute if you specified a MockAppDelegate?

Comment: Seems like the XCTest setup() function doesn't run early enough to keep the initialization code from running -- my first opportunity to replace the AppDelegate seems to come after the app is initialized, so it's starting the app with my original AppDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/:

Replace the app delegate in `main`. If you're using Xcode 7.0, 7.1 or 7.2, you have to include the testing app delegate in your production target:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TestingAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        BOOL isTesting = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestCase") != Nil;
        Class appDelegateClass = isTesting ? [TestingAppDelegate class] : [AppDelegate class];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(appDelegateClass));
    }
}
```

In Xcode 7.3, Apple has fixed things so that the testing app delegate can live in the testing target where it belongs:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class appDelegateClass = NSClassFromString(@"TestingAppDelegate");
        if (!appDelegateClass)
            appDelegateClass = [AppDelegate class];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(appDelegateClass));
    }
}
```

Here's how some folks are doing it in Swift. Instead of creating a TestingAppDelegate, they're just using `nil`:

```
import UIKit

private func delegateClassName() -> String? {
    return NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") == nil ? NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate) : nil
}

UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, delegateClassName())
```

For further discussion, see [How to Easily Switch Your App Delegate for Testing](https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/)

Comment: Ah! I've come across your blog many times and it has been very helpful every time!  Any idea where the Swift equivalent location for main would be?

Comment: @lonesomewhistle I've added a Swift example taken from the blog post discussion.